# Ротация логов по размеру

Tags: логирование, cron, crontab

Есть настройка `logrotate` для ротации логов при достижении ими 1GB. Но автоматически логи не ротируются при достижении ими нужного объема.
Я так понимаю надо `cron` задействовать (запуск нужного конфига `logrotate` каждые 5 минут), но как как сделать так, чтобы это не порушило работу других конфигов `logrotate`, которые запускаются раз в сутки?
Куда и как прописывать?

конфиг `/etc/logrotate.d/customizer_generator`

```
/storage/logs/customizer_generator/*.log {
    size 1G
    sharedscripts
    rotate 31
    delaycompress
    compress
    compresscmd /usr/bin/pigz
    compressoptions -p2
    postrotate
            test -s /run/syslogd.pid && kill -HUP $(cat /run/syslogd.pid)
            # postrotate script should always return 0
            true
    endscript
}
```

Comment: hourly не устраивает? У вас > 12GB в час в лог пишется?

Comment: @vp_arth, hourly не подойдет. Да, логов там огромное количество, за час сожрет больше, чем хотелось бы и рисковать потерей логов других систем не очень хочется...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**man logrotate**

> ```
>    size size
>           Log  files are rotated only if they grow bigger than size bytes.  If size is followed by k, the size
>           is assumed to be in kilobytes.  If the M is used, the size is in megabytes, and if G  is  used,  the
>           size is in gigabytes. So size 100, size 100k, size 100M and size 100G are all valid.  This option is
>           mutually exclusive with the time interval options, and it causes log files to be rotated without re-
>           gard  for  the  last  rotation time, if specified after the time criteria (the last specified option takes the precedence).
> ```

Правила, основанные на size не зависят от времени последнего запуска. Т.е. если к моменту запуска, размер достиг настроенной ёмкости, будет произведено ротирование.

Таким образом, осталось лишь запускать **logrotate** чаще. Правила основанные на временных интервалах(**daily**, **hourly**) при этом будут вести себя так же, как и раньше.

---

Сегодня, большинство дистрибутивов основано на **systemd**. В таких системах не нужно использовать **cron** для запуска **logrotate**:

```sh
$ cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/logrotate.timer 
[Unit]
Description=Periodic rotation of log files
Documentation=man:logrotate(8) man:logrotate.conf(5)

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*:0/5
AccuracySec=1s
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```